# Having difficulty when incrementing

Tags: assembly, ascii, dos, x86-16, emu8086

I have an issue with incrementing the number. It will come out as a love symbol. I don't know why.

```
reservationID dw 0 

.code

main proc
     mov ax,@data
     mov ds,ax

     mov ah,02h
     lea dx,reservationID
     add dx,30h  
     int 21h
```

Answer (score 1):

The DOS function that you use (02h) outputs the **character in the `DL` register**. What you did is loading the address of the *reservationID* variable in `DX`. That's not correct.

Seeing that you are adding 30h to convert to ASCII, I would suggest to define the variable using `db` instead of the larger than necessary `dw`.

```
.data

reservationID db 0

.code

main proc

  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax
  mov  dl, reservationID
  add  dl, 30h
  mov  ah, 02h
  int  21h
```